# Why using Log4Net instead of just writing to my db?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

We are discussing about implementing `Log4Net` in our system.
I used to work with it and I think it's useful, my friend is asking what would be the advantage of using it comparing to just writing to our DB when an exception occurs?

For example with `log4net`:

```
  catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("UserNamePasswordStatus.NotExist", ex);
            }
```

and with our code :

```
  catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _Params.Add("?Exception_", ex);
                DataAccessMgr.Instance.ExecProcedure("insert_AppLog", _Params, false);                
            }
```

What should I answer him?
thx

Comment: For example because you don´t have a DB? Or because of some Network-errors that prevent you from writing the error-message to the DB? Many possible reasons, though.

Comment: Simple - what happens when the exception is that the database is unavailable.

Comment: For the same reason you use any library, so you don't have to write and test code that someone else already has. (I'm assuming you plan to use Log4Net to write your logs to your DB).

Comment: @juharr we plan to use to write to our db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could argue for the same thing with writing to a file ... but i believe the main reason is :why reinvent something if you can reuse the above libraries.

You start with simple "logging" to your db ... and then you say ...hmm ... i would like to add timestamps, so you alter your table ... and then you think ... knowing where it came from is useful ... I should change my logging to keep track of that ... and then you say ... and then ... but then you remember ... and it keep going.

Personally, I find `NLog` easier that `log4net`. More activity on the project, more bells and whistles (here's a: [how to get started](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1052902/How-to-NLog-with-Visual-Studio) article). I really like using a logger because then I can redirect some messages to a file, and have some message [pop notifications on my desktop by simply configuring the logger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786304/Logging-How-to-Growl-with-NLog-or). You can keep going with examples, but what's the point of writing directly to your DB?
Wouldn't you have a DB wrapper to begin with, just to avoid exactly that?

Comment: We do have a DB wrapper, I thought that Log4Net has some advantages over it so we could stop using that wrapper and work with Log4Net.

Comment: Exactly the same idea. It makes the intent of your action clearer: `Log.Error(something_bad_happened)`. You know it's logging it. much cleaner than `myDbWrapper.Log(something_bad_happened)`. what about if you want to quickly mock something and see the results in your console app ... how do you do it with your DB wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

It's a personal choice but `Log4Net` manages the log in file system (in your disk) and so if you don't have a DB to log the error messages then you can go for it. Though, I see in most enterprise application people chose to log error in database than in file system for better auditing.

Again, if you use `NLog` which is written over `Log4Net` (available in NuGet) then you can log the errors in database as well using the same kind of syntax.

```
log.Error("UserNamePasswordStatus.NotExist", ex);
```

Comment: You don't need NLog to write the logs to a DB.  Log4Net has the ability to log to a DB by itself.

Comment: @juharr, that's good to know but my earlier use of `log4net` is to log in file system only.

Comment: As  you already said: "It´s a personal choice" making this question "primary opinion-based".

Comment: @Rahul , saying that there  is no advantage of log4net over any other custom wrapper it's also an answer.

Comment: @OffirPe'er, am not saying that neither my answer depicts that. Rather I am saying personal choices I have seen in many projects I have worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

There are obviously lot more advantages of using the Log4Net than the traditional way of dumping the logs into DB/Event viewer. It can be implemented with less no. of configuration steps for both large and small sized applications.

The interesting point is, it can be customized at each level to make it more reliable logging. I like the feature of rolling over mechanism(By size, by date and etc).